# Rest backend in a box?

Tags: json, rest, angularjs, backend

Iam looking for something like a Backend as a Service but that can be self-hosted.
These are the basic features I am looking for:

- Authentication / Access control
- JSON support
- Resources
- Basic business logic support
- Open source or easily extensible
- Should be compatible with e.g. angular.js

are there any REST-backend implementations out there  which can do most of the stuff like the Backend as a service providers (kinvey looks nice) can do but that I can host on an intranet?

regards Oskar

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I did a bit of playing around with Deployd for a personal project recently. It might fit the bill of what you're looking for:
http://deployd.com/

Comment: Deployd seems to fit the bill nicely! Great find!

Answer (score 1):

Although I've yet to use either, look into [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/) and [Backand](https://www.backand.com/) as well...

Comment: Backand is a rest api \ backend as a service that was tailored for AngularJS, even supports Angular 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

the next thing i want to try is [Dreamfactory](http://www.dreamfactory.com/), from what i've read it's perfect for a Backend with REST API and fits good to an AngularJS Frontend.

maybe you'll give it a shot aswell.

Answer (score 0):

You can check [Divroll Backend](https://github.com/divroll/backend), a Java based Backend Platform that can be used with Angular or any Javascript Framework through its REST Endpoint API.

It can be self-hosted in any server or application server as it is self-contained and does not required external modules (and databases).